# Python : How to ignore a delimited part of a sentence?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following line :

```
CommonSettingsMandatory = #<Import Project="[\\.]*Shared(\\vc10\\|\\)CommonSettings\.targets," />#,true
```

and i want the following output:

```
['commonsettingsmandatory', '<Import Project="[\\\\.]*Shared(\\\\vc10\\\\|\\\\)CommonSettings\\.targets," />', 'true'
```

If i do a simple regex with the comma, it will split the value if there's a value in it, like i wrote a comma after targets, it will split here.
So i want to ignore the text between the ## to make sure there's no splitting there.
I really don't know how to do!

Comment: What's your delimiter?  It seems you're using both `=` and `,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split

```
import re

string = 'CommonSettingsMandatory = #toto,tata#, true'
splitlist = re.split('\s?=\s?#(.*?)#,\s?', string)
```

Then `splitlist` contains `['CommonSettingsMandatory', 'toto,tata', 'true']`.

Comment: This sounded great, but it didn't work... it stills give me the complete string

Answer (score 0):

While you might be able to use split with a lookbehind, I would use the groups captured by this expression.

```
(\S+)\s*=\s*##([^#]+)##,\s*(.*)
```

`m = re.Search(expression, myString)`.  use `m.group(1)` for the first string, `m.group(2)` for the second, etc.

Comment: Lookbehind isn't needed. `re.split` will give you the value held by a capturing group in the splitting pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to split the string using spaces as delimiters, but you want to also remove any text between pound signs?

If that's correct, why not simply remove the pound sign-delimited text *before* splitting the string?

```
import re
myString = re.sub(r'#.*?#', '', myString)
myArray = myString.split(' ')
```

**EDIT: (based on revised question)**

```
import re
myArray = re.findall(r'^(.*?) = #(.*?)#,(.*?)$', myString)
```

That will actually return an array of tuples including your matches, in the form of:

```
[
    (
        'commonsettingsmandatory',
        '<Import Project="[\\\\.]*Shared(\\\\vc10\\\\|\\\\)CommonSettings\\.targets," />',
        'true'
    )
]
```

*(spacing added to illustrate the format better)*

Comment: I try to split using commas as delimiters.